# Java naming for setters without arguments

Tags: java, naming-conventions, conventions

We have a class with some independent states (enabled, disabled, readonly)

initially, those functions were named

```
enabled
disabled
readonly
```

which are not verbs and is not correct, so we were thinking of changing them to

```
setEnabled
setDisabled
setReadOnly
```

or even

```
setEnabledState
setDisabledState
setReadOnlyState
```

however, they are not getting any parameters, I'm wondering if that is correct or would we need to chose other wordings. I don't really need to add a constant to use something as `setState(State.Disabled)`

I know this may be opinionated but at the end of the day the API namings are almost a standard today.

Comment: So the object can be both enabled and disabled at the same time?

Comment: @Vlad One state will change the other.  All 3 are independent.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a convention or not for this, but I would call them `enable()`, `disable()` and `readOnly()`. Anyway, I guess the JavaDoc for the three methods should be pretty rich so to explain to the clients when they should use each - and I don't think they can guess it just from a naming convention.

Comment: Use an enum to represent the three states.

Comment: *"One state will change the other. All 3 are independent."* **--** That is not logical. If `enabled` and `disabled` are *independent* then they can be `true` at the same time just as @`Vlad L` mentioned. That simply does not make sense for the user of this code. Also: if they are independent, don't you need also methods to *reset* this variables?

Comment: Does *enabled* imply reading and writing permissions?